# Owl Carousel breaks when initialized in hidden container

Tags: owl-carousel

When Owl Carousel is initiated in a hidden element and that element is then displayed through a trigger, the width of the carousel items is completely wrong (until window gets resized):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93cpX/183/) (click on red link, see the broken layout appearing, then resize the window)

This issue was [discussed more than a year ago on Github](https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/issues/207), but nothing I can use. And Owl Carousel hasn't been updated since before the discussion.

Any suggestion?

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    loop:true,
    nav:true,
})

$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(".target").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem. Try `height: 0px` and `opacity: 0` instead of hiding and `height: 100%` and `opacity: 1` for showing. It worked for me.

Comment: Nice trick :) Works perfectly. I had ended up using Ajax but next time I'll use your trick, thanks!